# SQL Query: List all actors who appeared in 40 or more thrillers, in descending order

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

For the database schema:

```
actor (id, fname, lname, gender)
movie (id, name, year)
directors (id, fname, lname)
casts (pid, mid, role)
movie_directors (did, mid)
genre (mid, genre)
```

The task I am trying to solve is to:
List all actors who appeared in 40 or more thrillers, in descending order of the number of thrillers they appeared in. Return the actors’ first and last names and the number of thriller movies each of them appeared in.

The current query I am using is:

```
SELECT a.fname, a.lname, COUNT(DISTINCT m.id)
   FROM Actor a, Casts c, Movie m, genre g
   WHERE a.id = c.pid
     AND c.mid = m.id
     AND c.mid = g.mid
     AND g.genre = 'Thriller'
   GROUP BY a.id, a.fname, a.lname
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT m.id) >= 40
   ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT m.id) DESC
```

As this is a homework question, I have uploaded this response to Gradescope. It is returning only the result:

```
Test Failed: False is not true
```

which is not very helpful, and as a direct result makes it hard to find the error in my logic. I am also not able to post the verbatim wrong response as a result of the unhelpful error message. What is wrong with my query, and what can I change to make it work?

Comment: To me this looks OK, and Gradescope holds data for it? I mean u cannot run it anywhere else except there?

Comment: Yes, there are 6 questions total and this is the only one I am getting wrong. No test data was provided -- only the database schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing functionally wrong with your query, there must something wrong with GradeScope, whatever that is. Note that, you don't actually need to include `a.id` in your `GROUP BY`.

I'd prefer a more modern approach to joins, e.g. using the `JOIN` keyword.

[Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/44ca1b/11)

```
SELECT
      aim.fname,
      aim.lname,
      aim.movieCount
  FROM
      (
      SELECT
              a.fname,
              a.lname,
              COUNT(DISTINCT m.id) movieCount
         FROM
             actor a
           JOIN
             casts c
               ON c.pid = a.id
           JOIN
             movie m
               ON m.id = c.mid
           JOIN
             genre g
               ON g.mid = m.id
         WHERE
             g.genre = 'Thriller'
         GROUP BY
             a.fname,
             a.lname
      ) aim
  WHERE
      aim.movieCount > 39
  ORDER BY
      aim.movieCount DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for the modern approach, I'll make sure to look up more about joins later :)